# Let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $a|b$ and $b|a$. Show that $a ∈ \{b,−b\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $a|b$ and $b|a$. Show that $a ∈ \{b,−b\}$.

**My attempt**

Since  $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, we have that $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0.$

I think I can use this result that appears in the book I am studying... If  $a\mid b$ and $b\neq 0$, then $a\leq |b|$.  Thus, in this case $a\leq |b|$ and $b\leq|a|$. The problem is that I don't see how to relate these two inequalities to get what I want.

Comment: I think I already have it. If $a\leq|b|$  then $|a|\leq|b|$, no?

Comment: I suspect $a=b=0$ has $a | b$ and $b |a$.  Also $-5 \le |3|$ but $|-5| \not \le |3|$

Comment: @Henry but $-5$ does not divide to $3$

Comment: $0|0$ because $0 = k\cdot 0$ for all integers $k$.  So indeed $a=0;b=0$ *is* possible.  Note:  *Everything* divides $0$ because for any $m$ we will have $0 = m*0$.  But $0$ is the only thing that is divisible by $0$ because for any $m\ne 0$ we will never have $0 = k*m$.

Comment: $a|b$ implies $|a| \le |b|$ or $b=0$.  Can you see why?

Comment: Where did you learn that $a|b\implies a \le |b|$?  Could you prove the result $a|b\implies |a| \le |b|$ instead?

Comment: Oh, yeah.  $27|0$ but $27 \not \le 0$ so.....

Answer (score 4):

Another approach

If $a\mid b$, then  $b= n a$ for some integer $ n$.

Analogously, since $b\mid a$, $a= m b$ for some integer $m$.

So, $a= m b= m n a$, hence $mn=1$. But $m$ and $n$ are integers, so $m=n=1$ or $m=n=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

What does $a\mid b$ mean *literally*?

We have that $a\mid b$ so there is an integer, $k$, so that $b=ak$ and $b\mid a$ so there is an integer, $m$, so that $a = mb$ so $a = m(ak) = a(km)$.

If $a\ne 0$ then $km = 1$ and the only divisors of $1$ are $1$ and $-1$ so either $m=1$ and $a = 1\cdot b = b$.  Or $m=-1$ so $a = (-1)b = -b$.  So $a \in \{b,-b\}$.

But what if $a = 0$. (I don't see why you can claim $a\ne 0; b\ne 0$). We then $b =ak = b\cdot 0 = 0 = a$ and $a = b$.  So $a \in \{b,-b\}$.

So either way $a\in \{b,-b\}$.

Comment: You should know by now to right `a \mid b` rather than `a|b`.

Comment: @amWhy, No, $\,0\mid 0\, $ in number theory since $\,0\:\! x = 0\, $ is solvable (though some elementary textbooks (unnecessarily) restrict the definition of divisibility to nonzero divisors in order to help prevent analysts from imploding).

Comment: To my mind the definition of $a\mid b$ (and who cares if it is typed as $a|b$) is that there exists an integer, $k$ so that $b = ka$ and not that $\frac ba \in \mathbb Z$.  But definitions are arbitrary.  I won't argue that $0$ *does* divide $0$ but I'm not going to accept that it is universal that does *not* either.  I'd say it is up to the text.